# httpmodules(Classic Mode) Vs Modules (Integrated mode) not parsing request in the same way

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5, httpmodule, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have an ASP.NET FW 4.5 application, normally it is running under Classic Mode , and we use a HttpModule that parse every request to webpages.
The Module checks in the DB if the user has access.
No problem with that.

When we switch to integrated mode we put a < webserver > < module > as recommended in the migration guide.
**The problem is that the module is parsing every request to the application, also the css, jss and images.** 
In Classic mode this does not happen, only pages are parsed.
Is there a different behavior between classic and integrated?
The module implements methods like:

`private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
private void OnAuthorization(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: The difference you have described is *the* difference between integrated and classic mode.

Comment: So in classic mode only aspx pages are parsed?Where can i check the documentation of that? I didn't find anything. Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET FW4.5 has nothing to do with Classic ASP; they are completely different technologies. You should retag your question.

Comment: rettaged as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old but just in case somebody else finds it I'll provide the answer...

In integrated mode, any modules you provide in `<system.webserver>` are invoked for every IIS request (including non ASP.NET pages) unless you add a constraint via the `preCondition` attribute. e.g.

```
<system.webserver>
    <modules>
        <add preCondition="managedHandler" name="..." type="..."/>
    </modules>
</system.webserver>
```

Specifying `managedHandler` means the module will be invoked only for ASP.Net managed resources such as `.aspx` files, but not unmanaged resources such as html, images and javascript.

Note, however, this setting is overridden if you specify `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` on the `<modules>` element, which causes all modules (and your `Global.asax` class if present) to be notified about all requests.

There's a useful write-up of the Life Cycle of an IIS 7.x request on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx), but this does not mention the `preCondition` attribute.  However you can read about it in the [IIS Settings Schema documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690693(v=vs.90).aspx).

### TL;DR

You might be wondering how it's possible that a module can be invoked for a non-managed resource when the event handlers defined in your `Global.asax` file are not invoked. After all, modules register their event handlers with the `HttpApplication` object that is passed to the `IHttpModule.Init` method like this:-

```
public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication context)
{
    context.AuthenticateRequest += my_request_handler;
}
```

The `HttpApplication` passed to `Init` is the same as that defined in `Global.asax`, so why aren't the Global application event handlers invoked?  The answer is simply that when a module registers its event handlers with the `HttpApplication` object, the `HttpApplication` is aware that it is in module initialization mode, and registers the event handlers separately, along with flags to indicate if the event handler should be called for non-managed resources.  You can investigate further by looking at the 
[HttpApplication reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs).